# How to convert Javascript numbers to a string and pass it to an input box

Tags: javascript

i'm stuck trying to convert feet to miles. here is my code so far:

```js
function convertData() {
  var distance = document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML;
  var mile     = 5280;
  var result   = distance /mile;
  document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = result;
};
```

and from the answer here, i'm trying to implement this to the

document.getElementById tag up in the beginning of the document found here..

```html
<input type="button" value='Convert to Miles' onclick="convertData();">

<input id="distance" type="number" value=453454>
```

..so when a user clicks that button, the data gets converted.
this is the default line when a user opens a page on first try:

any advice or thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function convertData() {
  var distance = document.getElementById('distance').value;
  var mile = 5280;
  var result = distance / mile;
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = +result;
};
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
<input type="button" value='Convert to Miles' onclick="convertData();">
<input id="distance" type="number" value=453454>
```

I will recommend displaying the answer in another element, and leaving the input free for the user to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest way

html inputs with a `type=number` have the `valueAsNumber` property to directly process their numeric value.
(There is also a `valueAsDate` for those of `type=date`)

```js
const
  distance_el = document.getElementById('distance')
,  mile       = 5280
   ;
function convertData()
  {
  distance_el.valueAsNumber /= mile
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Convert to Miles" onclick="convertData();">

<input id="distance" type="number" value="453454">
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be getting/setting the input `value` property rather than the `innerHTML`.

The [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property is used to return the HTML content of an element, while the `value` property is used to return the value of a text field.

```js
function convertData() {
  var distance = document.getElementById('distance').value;
  var mile = 5280;
  var result = distance / mile;
  document.getElementById('distance').value = result;
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value='Convert to Miles' onclick="convertData();">
<input id="distance" type="number" value=453454>
```

Simplified version:

```js
function convertData(t) {
  t.nextElementSibling.value = t.nextElementSibling.value/5280;
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value='Convert to Miles' onclick="convertData(this);">
<input id="distance" type="number" value=453454>
```

Comment: also he may need parseInt() function

Comment: Ok thanks guys. all suggestions worked. However do you guys know how to clear the input box once somebody enters a number?